# Combined gsuite and gcp billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite

Hi I am trying to consolidate our billing and would like if possible to include the gsuite billing and payment account into my main GCP billing account - is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to combine your G-Suite and GCP billing accounts, I would suggest that you get into [contact with the billing team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) as they will have the resources necessary to help in your request.

If you have any other questions or concerns about this inquiry, please do not hesitate to contact me by replying to this post. I will be more than happy to help at that time.